# Add struct to vector: "no matching constructor for initialization" error when compiling on macos

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, c++20

I'm using `emplace_back` to add `struct`s to a `std::vector` as follows:

```cpp
struct ConfigurableShaderParameter
{
    std::string variableName;
    std::string description;
    float defaultValue;
    float min;
    float max;
    float step;
    float value;
};

std::vector<ConfigurableShaderParameter> parameters;

std::string variableName, description;
float defaultValue, min, max, step;
// Initialize the above variables
parameters.emplace_back(variableName, description, defaultValue, min, max, step, defaultValue);
```

The project is built using CMake and C++20 and it's cross-platform: it compiles fine under Ubuntu and Windows but I cannot get it to compile under macos-latest (I'm using github actions, I don't have access to a mac).

This is the error message:

```
/Users/runner/work/epoch/epoch/src/frontend/src/ConfigurableShader.cpp:41:30: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::vector<epoch::frontend::ConfigurableShaderParameter>::emplace_back<std::string &, std::string &, float &, float &, float &, float &, float &>' requested here
                m_parameters.emplace_back(variableName, description, defaultValue, min, max, step, defaultValue);
                             ^
/Applications/Xcode_14.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/construct_at.h:35:16: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Tp = epoch::frontend::ConfigurableShaderParameter, _Args = <std::string &, std::string &, float &, float &, float &, float &, float &>]: no matching constructor for initialization of 'epoch::frontend::ConfigurableShaderParameter'
constexpr _Tp* construct_at(_Tp* __location, _Args&& ...__args) {
               ^
1 error generated.
```

My main CMakeLists.txt file includes the following directives and nothing else:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
```

The project is open-source, so if you wish you can see the entire failed build message here: https://github.com/ghidosoft/epoch/actions/runs/7992320133/job/21825555388?pr=1#step:5:226

What can I do to fix the error?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At issue here is that until C++20, when initializing an aggregate you have to use `{}` for the initializer like

```
foo bar{baz};
```

In C++20 that rule was updated to allow `()` to work with aggregates.  This was introduced via [P0960R3](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0960r3.html) but it has not yet been included in apple-clang which is why you are getting the error only with that compiler.

To work around this you can give `ConfigurableShaderParameter` a proper constructor like

```
struct ConfigurableShaderParameter
{
    ConfigurableShaderParameter(std::string variableName, std::string description, float defaultValue, float min, float max, float step, float value)
       : variableName(variableName), description(description), defaultValue(defaultValue), min(min), max(max), value(value) {}
    std::string variableName;
    std::string description;
    float defaultValue;
    float min;
    float max;
    float step;
    float value;
};
```

Comment: Well, that explains why it does not work on macos. Thanks a lot, it works.

Comment: @aghidini No problem.  If you need a MacOS binary you can install gcc or clang via homebrew and compile with that.  Not sure if that is something github supports.

Answer (score 2):

`emplace_back()` is looking for a constructor that doesn't exist in the struct:

https://onlinegdb.com/4JjUZWNy5

> error: no matching function for call to ‘ConfigurableShaderParameter::ConfigurableShaderParameter(std::__cxx11::basic_string&, std::__cxx11::basic_string&, float&, float&, float&, float&, float&)’

So you will have to add it explicitly, eg:

```
struct ConfigurableShaderParameter
{
    std::string variableName;
    std::string description;
    float defaultValue;
    float min;
    float max;
    float step;
    float value;

    ConfigurableShaderParameter(
        std::string a_variableName,
        std::string a_description,
        float a_defaultValue,
        float a_min,
        float a_max,
        float a_step,
        float a_value)
    : variableName(a_variableName),
      description(a_description),
      defaultValue(a_defaultValue),
      min(a_min),
      max(a_max),
      step(a_step),
      value(a_value)
    {}
};
```

https://onlinegdb.com/1N4LVuYCQ